# How to extract argument of MeshRegion-Object?

Tags: mesh

Consider examplary a MeshRegion-Object

```
test = MeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2,1/2}, {2, -1/2}}, {Line[{1, 2}], Line[{2, 3}],Line[{3, 4}],Line[{4, 2}]}];
```

Looking inside `test` I get

```
??test
(*Global`test
 MeshRegion[...]*)
```

To extract the arguments of `MeshRegion` I usually try

```
test /. MeshRegion->List
```

which doesn't work in this example?

What might be the reason? Is there a workaround? Thanks

Comment: hint: `AtomQ[test]` gives `True`.

Comment: maybe `MeshCoordinates[test]`and `MeshCells[test, 1]` or `MeshCells[test, All]`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks, that would return the "input arguments".  My goal is to pick everything inside the `MeshRegion[...]`-expression which `??test` returns.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't. `MeshRegion` is atomic. The "input form" *may* not even correspond accurately to the internal representation (though I believe in this case it does).  Use the documented API if you need guarantees and protection from breakage in special cases or future/past versions.  All that said, check out my community wiki answer (or Carl's `Nucleus`) in the QA I linked above.

Comment: Ulricht,do you have some insight on [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49096167#49096167) from chat?

Comment: @ user21 I think `Mesh` is an option for Plot3D&Co and `MeshRegion` is some kind of mesh-object. Sorry, no more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
ReleaseHold[ToExpression[ToBoxes[InputForm[test]][[1, 1]], StandardForm, Hold] /. 
  MeshRegion -> List]
```

> {{{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {2., 0.5}, {2., -0.5}}, {Line[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}}]}}

Or

```
ReleaseHold[MakeExpression[ToBoxes[InputForm[test]][[1, 1]], StandardForm] /. 
  MeshRegion -> List]
```

> {{{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {2., 0.5}, {2., -0.5}}, {Line[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}}]}}